# Converting mongoshell projection to Spring MongoTemplate projection

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Given following mongoshell query - which works fine

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'id': '1'
    }
  }, {
    '$graphLookup': {
      'from': 'pages', 
      'startWith': '$cID', 
      'connectFromField': 'parent', 
      'connectToField': 'cID', 
      'as': 'result', 
      'depthField': 'level'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$result', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      'result.level': 1
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$id', 
      'result': {
        '$push': '$result'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'result': {
        'id': 1, 
        'cID': 1, 
        'level': 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

How do I achieve the projection using the Spring MongoTemplate and the its given DSL?
Given the source and the `AggregationTests` provided by the github repo, I could be

```
project().and("result").nested(Fields.fields("id","cID","level")
```

which just returns an empty result list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't come up with a solution to make it work with the `MongoTemplate` directly. As I'm already using the `MongoRepository` given by Spring Data, creating an aggregation query is quite straightforward.

```java
public interface Repository extends MongoRepository<Object, String> {
  @Aggregation(pipeline = {
    "{'$match': {'cID': '?0'}}",
    "{'$graphLookup': {'from': 'pages', 'startWith': '$cID', 'connectFromField': 'cID', 'connectToField': 'parent', 'as': 'result', 'depthField': 'level'}}",
    "{'$unwind': {'path': '$result', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true}}",
    "{'$sort': {'result.level': -1}}",
    "{'$group': {'_id': '$id', 'result': {'$push': '$result'}}}",
    "{'$project': {'cID_list': '$result.cID', 'result': {'level': 1, 'cID': 1, 'id': 1}}}"
  })
  AggregationResults<Map<?, List<String>>> getChildrencIDs(final String cID);
}
```